# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (14) beyond bounds (14)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, uitableview

I am new to be iOS developer. I am making an app in which i am getting response from JSON. But when i am click button for show next UITableView.
I have two questions for everyone.

1.)It's will shown empty value before. I must scroll down for show values.

2.)After scroll down debug error are show "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (14) beyond bounds (14)"

[image: Picture for shown scroll down to show datas]

Sorry for my bad english. I can speak english a little bit.

We must click button for go to next UITableView.

```
- (IBAction)btnf10
{
    NSMutableDictionary *content = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [content setValue:[[AppSetting sharedInstance] token] forKey:@"ewitoken"];
    //[content setValue:gloablOnWherehouse.selectedWhereHouse forKey:@"model_Name"];
    [[EWIConnector connector] requestEWIService:@"special_selected_f10" requestData:content delegate:self];
}
```

And requestEWIServiceStart will check String.

```
    - (void) requestEWIServiceStart:(EWIConnector *)connector{

        NSLog(@"start %@",connector.endpoint);
    }

    - (void) requestEWIServiceFinish:(EWIConnector *)connector responseData:(NSDictionary *)responseData{

        NSLog(@"finish %@",connector.serviceName);
        NSLog(@"response %@",responseData);

        if ([connector.serviceName isEqualToString:@"special_selected_f10"])
        {
            NSLog(@"finish %@",connector.serviceName);
            NSDictionary *content = responseData[@"content"];
            NSString *stAlertMes = [content objectForKey:@"alertMessage"];
            stAlertMes = [self getString:stAlertMes];
            NSLog(@"AlertMSG : %@", stAlertMes);
            if (![stAlertMes isEqualToString:@""]) {
                NSLog(@"ALERT MESSAGE : %@", stAlertMes);
                gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected = [[NSArray alloc] init];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"HAS DATA");
                gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected = [content objectForKey:@"DataList_SPI_DetailCollection"];
                [self.tableViewWhereHoseList reloadData];

                labelStatus.text = @"F11";

            }
        }
       else
    {
        NSLog(@"response %@",responseData);
    }
}
```

UITableView 2 for response data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    globlOnDisplayEffect = [GlobalVariable sharedInstance];
    globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelectedWhereHouse = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [self.tableViewDetailList reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return (globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected)?[globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected count]: 100;
}



- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell";
    DisplayEffectQtyViewCell *cell = [self.tableViewDetailList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    } else {
        if (globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected) {
            NSMutableArray *myMutbleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [myMutbleArray addObject:globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected];

            if (myMutbleArray) {
                NSDictionary *myDic = [globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSDictionary *cont = [myDic objectForKey:@"DataList_SPI_DetailF10"];
                NSString *f10_cmpt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_cmpt"]];
                NSString *f10_dt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_dt"]];
                NSString *f10_item = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_item"]];
                NSString *f10_lot = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_lot"]];
                NSString *f10_model = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_model"]];
                NSString *f10_of = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_of"]];
                NSString *f10_semi = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_semi"]];
                NSString *f10_tm = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_tm"]];
                NSString *f10_uncmp = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_uncmp"]];

                [cell setf10_cmpt:f10_cmpt setf10_dt:f10_dt setf10_item:f10_item setf10_lot:f10_lot setf10_model:f10_model setf10_of:f10_of setf10_semi:f10_semi setf10_tm:f10_tm setf10_uncmp:f10_uncmp];


            }
        }
    }
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint to see where you error happens.

Comment: When i'm exception breakpoint. It's error on  
"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell *cell = [self.tableViewDetailList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];" After i'm scroll down from blank cell to shown value on cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index Bound of array, it's a common problem. There is no object in 14th position in your array.

Before loading tableview, NSLog all data using a loop in console which you have to show in Cell.

```
  else
        {
            NSLog(@"HAS DATA");
            gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected = [content objectForKey:@"DataList_SPI_DetailCollection"];

           // [self.tableViewWhereHoseList reloadData];

            labelStatus.text = @"F11";

        }
```

And also check which table view you are loading and get it count. I think , it should be

```
 [globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected count]>0 ?[globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected count]:100.
```

Explain, why you will show 100 cell when [globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected count]==0. And what is the data source for else ?

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 // NSLog what you return.... 
return (globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected)?[globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected count]: 100;
}
```

Check you table cell condition also. **

Comment: Oh,sorry for wrong return value(100). I'm will write value for return is 1.
Now you're code can resolve my problem. But i'm have a question.
How can resolve first question. Because i must only scroll down for show data.

Comment: Please, fix it first. Hope second problem will be solved automatically. Your table cell is not getting data for cell, as a result it crashes. If you get solution, please, upvote and accept my answer. @รัฐพงศ์ ตุรงค์เรือง

Comment: I'm fix follow you comment. It's work (It's not error from array). But UITable can't response data until scroll down. Please help me.

Comment: in tablecell, if (globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected) is always true man ! try to change condition. Print the cell object before going its inside

Comment: Can you show me an example? Because i'm new developer. I have a little experience.

Comment: NP. Think an example of table view simply. First get all value in array, suppose you get 10 data , so load 10 row table in view without data, and  try to NSLog the each value in cellforindex method you need.

Comment: Yes, My condition is always true. But i don't know to add anything on the new conditions for Print the cell object before going its inside.